# What does "(v) ->" mean in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, folding

When in Android Studio I will often see my anonymous inner class for a View.onClickListener compressed to a (v)-> until I click on it, much the same way my code will display as if strings are hard-coded when my code uses a string resource id.  Google searches for '"(v) ->" android' are not giving me anything.
Is this some more advanced compact coding notation that I can use?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which is a feature of Java 8 and is not yet supported in Android. In your case, it is just the `onClick`'s `View` parameter. It is the android studio to compact anonymous inner classes.

Comment: So - is this something that android studio just does to make the code more readable?  Can I not use it as a coding shortcut?

Comment: it's not just android studio. It is called [lamba expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). I dunno if android support it tough

Comment: ok.  I remember learning about lambda expressions, but when I moved from my general java texts to my android java texts, I got the impression that lamdas were not supported in android yet.

Comment: yes, it's pure eye pleasure to increase readability. You *could* it as a shortcut if we were allowed to use Java 8 and it's lambda expressions, but that's not the case (yet).

Comment: yep, lambda expressions are part of Java 8, which is not yet supported

Comment: I think this is not a Lambda expression. I usually get that kind of notation when Android studio is trying to make my code more readable. In fact, when I click once on, it spreads the initial state of my code.

Comment: it is not a real Lambda expression. It is android studio that for the readability purpose mimics it, @StanimirYakimov

Comment: @Blackbelt That's exactly what I want to say. :)

Answer (score 2):

Android does not support lambdas. Android Studio does this so the code *looks* like the latest Java.